# Zeppelin context not defined for angular

Tags: angular, binding, apache-zeppelin

What I try to do :

- User draws a polygon on a map which polygon then will be used to calculate the count of kids inside it

To do that im using angular and then I need to pass this polygon somehow to python so I can calculate the count of kids inside it.

I’ve understood that zeppelin notebook has this function called zeppelin-context to pass objects/variables between interpreters. Unfortunately it only works for me with pyspark:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgxad.png)

I tried running this code :

```
if (type === 'polygon') {
    console.log(layer.getLatLngs());
    z.angularBind('coordinates', JSON.stringify(layer.getLatLngs()));
```

but keep getting this error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: z is not defined.

Any idea why is this happening? And how to define zeppelin-context in angular?